# Google Apps Script/Saving google sheet as CSV is taking older version of sheet instead of latest version

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to GAS and this is my first real project so please bear with me!  So I'm editing a specific sheet in a google spreadsheet.  I'm doing 3 edits to it:

1. Edit the header row
2. to add custom fields
3. imports all the data from another sheet to this sheet

and then I export into google drive as a CSV.  Everything works but somehow, when I open the CSV, I only see the first 2 steps and not the last step (trying to open the CSV with all 3 steps done)

Here is the method that makes all the main function calls

```
  var sheetBatch1 = createNewSheet("Batch1")
  formatSheetBatch(sheetBatch1) <--- step 1
  populateSheetbatch(arrayNonTestEmails, sheetBatch1, 1) <--- step 2 and step 3 happen in here
  saveAsCSV(sheetBatch1)
```

Below is the "download as CSV" method.  The logger will output the URL and when I paste it in the URL, it downloads onto my local drive with the correct CSV.  So why does the one saved in Google Drive just have steps 1 and 2 done and the downloaded one has all 3 steps done?

```
function saveAsCSV(sheet) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ssId = ss.getId()
  var sheetName = sheet.getName()
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId()

  var folder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next()
  var fileName = sheetName + ".csv"
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssId + "/export?exportFormat=csv&format=csv" + "&gid=" + sheetId

  Logger.log("method saveAsCSV: url " + url)
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  })
  folder.createFile(response.getBlob().setName(fileName))
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About `Everything works but somehow, when I open the CSV, I only see the first 2 steps and not the last step (trying to open the CSV with all 3 steps done)`, although I cannot know your actual script, if your showing 3 functions `createNewSheet`, `formatSheetBatch`, and `populateSheetbatch` work fine, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
var sheetBatch1 = createNewSheet("Batch1")
formatSheetBatch(sheetBatch1) <--- step 1
populateSheetbatch(arrayNonEmails, sheetBatch1, 1) <--- step 2 and step 3 happen in here
saveAsCSV()
```

#### To:

```
var sheetBatch1 = createNewSheet("Batch1")
formatSheetBatch(sheetBatch1) <--- step 1
populateSheetbatch(arrayNonEmails, sheetBatch1, 1) <--- step 2 and step 3 happen in here

SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Added

saveAsCSV()
```

#### Note:

- This modification supposes that your showing 3 functions `createNewSheet`, `formatSheetBatch`, and `populateSheetbatch` work fine. Please be careful about this.
- This modification is just my guess. Although I cannot know your actual script, if `flush()` method has already been used and your current issue occurs, please provide your whole script. By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: hi! We can assume those functions are working as expected because when I take the outputted URL and paste it, it downloads a file to my local drive with all the correct information. i tried flush() and it didn't work :(. i edited the post with more information.  let me know if there is anything else that is needed!

Comment: @Kinkikowboi Thank you for replying. About `We can assume those functions are working as expected because when I take the outputted URL and paste it, it downloads a file to my local drive with all the correct information.`, in this case, I guess that you might have downloaded it using the URL after the script was done. In this case, the result data is included. In your current situation, I thought that the CSV data is retrieved while the script was running. So, I proposed to use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` to save the current situation while the script is running.

Comment: @Kinkikowboi But, you say `i tried flush() and it didn't work`. In this case, it is required to correctly replicate your situation. But, in your question, your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue is not included. So, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating `i tried flush() and it didn't work`? By this, I would like to confirm it. I deeply apologize that I cannot correctly imagine your whole script. I think that this is due to my poor skill.

Comment: WAIT.  I just tried adding flush again this morning and it worked!  Why didn't it work before?  THANK YOU!  Before posting here, I've been hammering this out for a couple days and couldn't figure it out.  THANK YOU THANK YOU!  If I could like your post forever, I would.

Comment: @Kinkikowboi Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

**The variable folder is not a Folder**

getFileById() returns a file.

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next()
```

should be something like:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(ss.getId()).getParents().next()
```

- [Folder.createFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(BlobSource))
- [DriveApp.getFileById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)
- [DriveApp.getFolderById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)

Comment: oh good catch, that's my bad!  I meant to rename it from "folder = ..." to "file = ..."